# Transform scale not scaling properly

Tags: javascript, css

I have code below that scale an image when pinch.It is scaling but the issue is it is always scale the image on upper left part.It doesn't scale on the part of image where I pinched. Any ideas on what is missing? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 input </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        window.onload = function() {

            document.myStartDist = 0
            document.myScale = 1.0
            document.myOnlyZoomLarger = 'false' /*if true page only can zoom larger, false allows page to shrink */

            document.getElementById('myDiv1').style.WebkitTransformOrigin = '0px 0px';
            document.getElementById('myDiv1').style.webkitTransform = 'scale(0.3)';

            myBodyId.ontouchstart = function(event) {
                myFinger0 = event.touches[0]
                myFinger1 = event.touches[1]
                document.myStartDist = parseFloat(myFinger0.clientY) - parseFloat(myFinger1.clientY)
            }

            myBodyId.ontouchmove = function(event) {
                if (event.touches.length == 2) { /*check if only two fingers on the device*/
                    myFinger0 = event.touches[0]
                    myFinger1 = event.touches[1]
                    myNewWidth = parseInt(myFinger0.clientY) - parseInt(myFinger1.clientY)
                    myChangeX = myNewWidth / document.myStartDist

                    document.myScale = myChangeX
                    if (document.myScale > 1.3) {
                        document.myScale = 1.3

                    }

                    if (document.myOnlyZoomLarger == 'false') {
                        if (document.myScale < 0.1) { /*so web page does not fully disapear*/
                            document.myScale = 0.1
                        }
                        document.getElementById('myDiv1').style.webkitTransform = 'scale(' + document.myScale + ')';
                    }

                    if (document.myOnlyZoomLarger == 'true') {
                        if (document.myScale < 1) { /*resets webpage to original size*/
                            document.myScale = 1.0
                            document.getElementById('myDiv1').style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1.0)';
                            console.log("scale 1.0");
                        } else {
                            document.getElementById('myDiv1').style.webkitTransform = 'scale(' + document.myScale + ')';
                        }
                    }
                } /*end touches  */ 
            } /*end ontouchmove*/
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv1">
        <img src="https://s14.postimg.org/timfv18sx/SMRT_Map_Sept16.png" id="pinch-zoom-image-id"  />
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: why there are 2 body tags in your code? And one without an end tag?

Comment: Typo error.Updated it.

Comment: You're setting style.WebkitTransformOrigin to the top left at the beginning of the code. I think you should change that to the center point between the 2 fingers.

Comment: Thanks @JonasGrumann! It works